# storing array in database when checkbox is not checked

Tags: laravel

Im using Laravel 7 and trying to save opening hours to database.
Im using checkbox and time fields for each day of week. If all the days are selected, it stores to database with no problem. If the day is not checked It doesn't store the dayi. i need it to be saved inactive.
here is my view and controller files. What am i doing wrong here??

```
<td>
    <div class=" weekDays-selector">
        <input type="checkbox" id="day-mon" class="weekday" name="day[]" value="1" @if($days['0']->status == 'active') checked @endif />
        <label for="day-mon">Monday </label>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true" @if($days['0']->status == 'inactive') style="display: none" @endif id="mon-from">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
        </span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="09:00" name="from[]" autocomplete="off" value="{{\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s',$days['0']->from)->format('G:i')}}">
    </div>
</td>
```

Controller

```
$from               = $request->from;
        $to                 = $request->to;
        $day                = $request->day;
        
        for( $count = 0; $count < 7; $count++ )
            {
              $newday                = new Day;
              $newday->vendor_id     = $setting->id;
              $newday->day           = $count+1;
              $newday->from          = $request->day[$count]  ? $from[$count] : '00:00:00';
              $newday->to            = $request->day[$count]  ? $to[$count] : '00:00:00';
              $newday->status        = $request->day[$count]  ? 'active' : 'inactive';
              $newday->save();
```

Comment: Remember that if a checkbox is not checked, nothing is sent to the server via form submission. You can kinda get around that by using Laravel's default logic: `$to = $request->input("to.{$count}", 0)`, which would be 1 if you checked it, or 0 if you didn't, but I'm a little unclear on your issue. Is there any error being generated by your code?

Comment: no error created. it just doesn't save it. so lets say if friday is uncheck, it saves 6 days and last is unsaved.i dont know maybe i have got a wrong approach to the issue.. all i need to is to collect the opening hours for the shops.. i created a relationship too.. so it is all saved to another table..